# The Maharal and his influence on Jewish philosophy

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, maharal

In the [Wiki article on the Maharal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Loew_ben_Bezalel) there is a quote by [Rabbi Yitzchak Adlerstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Adlerstein) citing [Rabbi Nachman Bulman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachman_Bulman) that the Maharal "prevented the [Balkanization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkanization#Other_uses) of Jewish thought".

I understand what he is saying literally, but I don't know what he means. Can someone please provide a clear explanation of what Rabbi Bulman is trying to say ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I haven't seen what Rabbis Adlerstein or Bluman said directly, the Wikipedia article is saying that the Maharal bridged Kabbalah with other branches of Jewish philosophy, making it accessible to those who do not learn or understand Kabbalah directly.

This prevented a situation where those who learn and know Kabbalah would have a completely different philosophical basis than those who don't, and those who don't would have followed the views of the Rishonim that the Maharal rejected.

Comment: I agree, but there could be another meaning as well: the Maharal attempted to unify Jewish philosophy and study of aggada (and to a lesser extent, halakha as well) which wasn't much of a concern for earlier Jewish philosophers